# Why doesn't ArcGIS rasterize every polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-conversion

I am trying to rasterize elements from a vector map but somehow ArcGIS only lets me rasterize 15 objects. I added a new field so that every object would get the same value. The original layer had 87 objects in it. Why do I now only get 15 in the rasterized layer?

[image]
The operation

[image]

The target area

[image]

The original table

[image]

The table after rasterizing

I've done this many times before and I can't figure out what is going wrong..

Comment: Your values are all the same, that is how the raster data structure works.  If you want unique values then you have to produce a field with unique values

Comment: Thats not the problem, the problem is that it only converst 15 out of the 87 elements. The values are supposed to be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your objects seem to be very small. If you don't have a conversion for all of them, this is probably because they do not include any cell center. As you seem to look for a "one polygon<-> one pixel" relationship, you should try converting your polygons to centroids, then use "point to raster" instead of "feature to raster".

Comment: Good catch.  The parameter is set to cell size 90. If all is in metres this would mean that any polygon whose shape area is 8100m2 and larger will be ignored. Either converting centroids as you suggest or dropping the resolution may also work.

Comment: The problem indeed was the fact that my polygons were really small.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because Arcgis rasterize tool can only rasterize the polygon which covers the centroid of the raster grid. Maybe you can use Qgis or R to deal with this. Both of them have a parameter which is "all touched", which means even if the polygons are very small and do not exactly cover the centroid of the output grid, they still can return the value to the output raster grid.

Though for ArcGis, it provides the parameter
cell_assignment(Optional):
The method to determine how the cell will be assigned a value when more than one feature falls within a cell.
CELL_CENTER—The polygon that overlaps the center of the cell yields the attribute to assign to the cell.
MAXIMUM_AREA—The single feature with the largest area within the cell yields the attribute to assign to the cell.
MAXIMUM_COMBINED_AREA—If there is more than one feature in a cell with the same value, the areas of these features will be combined. The combined feature with the largest area within the cell will determine the value to assign to the cell.
This is convenient for multiple field polygons that need to be rasterized other than only one field needing to be returned to the output raster.